# If file exists in folder read it else skip the processing part

Tags: r, file-exists, read.table

I am reading in several *.csv, where the names and paths are determined at runtime.

However sometimes there are files with do not exist. For this file I need kind of exception handling.

Currently I am reading in my files with:

```
    companyFileName <- paste("C://Users//Prices//",companiesIsin,".csv")
df <- read.csv(gsub(" ","", companyFileName, fixed=TRUE), header = TRUE, sep = ";",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

When the file does not exist in the folder I am getting an error. Is there something like exception handling in R?

I appreciate your reply!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can check if a file exists using the function `file.exists`. So you might check for file existence before trying to read it in to avoid an error, e.g.

```
if (file.exists(companyFileName))
   df <- read.csv(gsub(" ","", companyFileName, fixed=TRUE), header = TRUE, sep = ";",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

**EDIT**:
You may also simplify the creation of the path and use read.csv2 for the `;` separator.
This makes it a bit more readable.

```
f <- paste0("C://Users//Prices//",companiesIsin,".csv")
if (file.exists(f))
  df <- read.csv2(f, TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thx for your answer! btw which path is it checking because I am always going into the `else` clause. btw I am running on windows 7.

Answer (score -1):

This code can be used to check if a file exits in a folder with date format as TRUE or FALSE.

```
setwd("D:\\FILEFOLDER")

datafile<-file.exists(paste0('DATA_',format(Sys.Date()-1,'%Y%m%d'),'.gz'))

voicefile<-file.exists(paste0('VOICE_TEXT_',format(Sys.Date()-1,'%Y%m%d'),'.gz'))
```